# Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress mvc with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i am creating a web app with mvc with angularjs,

i am trying to insert the records in my database but i am getting the following error

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
>       at angular.js:38
>       at n (angular.js:18524)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:18259)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (angular.js:26999)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.js:8171)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (jquery-3.1.1.js:8239)
>       at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:368)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:157)

this is how my code looks

```
    $scope.insertdata = function () {
        $scope.students = {};
        $scope.students.name = $scope.stdname;
        $scope.students.fullname = $scope.stdfname;
        $scope.students.address = $scope.stdaddress;
        $scope.students.city = $scope.stdcity;
        $scope.students.country = $scope.stdcountry;
        $scope.students.contno = $scope.stdcontno;
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/dashboardquot/insert_employee",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: $scope.students
        }).then(function (response) {
            angular.element('#closemodel').trigger('click');
        })
    }
```

the data is being inserted but still getting this error
what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What's getdata() doing? Where is that code?

Comment: @rrd updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line is causing the error:

```
angular.element('#closemodel').trigger('click');
```

This is because the click event is bound to some code that is lead to call $digest multiple times. Try wrapping this line in $timeout.

Comment: thank you its work please upvote my question if you think it deserve